I am only using the plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended preset rule set,Why am I getting no-var errors?
1、When I use ESLint to check my code, there is a rule that targets the var keyword, and the rule name is no-var.  the no-var rule is a native rule of ESLint. However, I am only using the 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended' preset rule set and haven't used the native ESLint rule set. Why am I getting no-var errors?
"Please help me solve the problems mentioned above."

Even if you are using that specific preset rule, the core rules of ESLint are still active I believe :) You would have to specifically ignore it

You need to add a rule to ignore no-var specifically in your .eslintrc.js or .eslintrc.json file.
Add this to your eslint file:
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-var': 'off', // Disable the no-var rule
  },
};


Hi, I know I can disable this rule through rules, but I don't understand why in my project, even though I'm only using the preset set of rules from typescript-eslint, native ESLint rules still trigger errors. Can you help me understand this?
